# VS Code launch chrome no longer works

Tags: macos, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, launch

All of a sudden I can no longer start a chrome launch

MacOS Ventura 13.2.1

```
    {
      "name": "ui",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "pre-ui",
      "url": "http://localhost:4581",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/ui/projects/app",
    },
```

It gives:
Unable to launch browser: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Stable')"
[image: error dialog]

installed previous version of VS Code 1.75.1; same problem
Googled for the non-descriptive error message. Nothing relevant found

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get things running again by disabling 'Javascript Debugger (Nightly)' extension and enabling the default 'Javascript Debugger'. Last night's update most probably had an issue.